# Can I use a JS function to call a HTML grid on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm creating sort of a demo for a type of CRM, and instead of creating 5 separate pages, I want to create a single page and when the user selects one of 4 options from a dropdown menu.

I thought it would be simpler to have that selection (1-4) call a JS function which then displays the x4 column, x2 row grid - dependent on the options selected, a different grid would display.

So if selection 1 is selected and the 'go' button is clicked, grid 1 will display underneath the initial options. if selection 2 is chosen, then grid 2 will display after 'go' button is clicked and so on.

Is it possible to do something like this? I haven't seen it before and so far no google searches have shown me anything but using JavaScript inside HTML.

Any info would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've been asked to add code to the question, but I honestly have no idea if this is even possible or how I would start it. I only have some pseudo-code that might help:

```
user selects option 1-4 from dropdown input box in HTML and clicks 'enter' button
       if user selects option 1
          display html grid 1 underneath original HTML code for input and 
          submission
      
       else if user selects option 2
          display html grid 2 underneath original HTML code for input and 
          submission
 
        else if user selects option 3
          display html grid 3 underneath original HTML code for input and 
          submission 

        else if user selects option 4
          display html grid 4 underneath original HTML code for input and 
          submission
```

Comment: You should add code to your question.

Comment: No code to add - i'm not even sure if this is possible, wouldnt know where to start. But I suppose Pseudo code might help?

Comment: Well, it is very unlikely someone is going to post a solution here. You should show your efforts and show where exactly you are stuck. Narrow down your question to where specifically you cannot make it work. Your question is one click away from being closed...

Comment: Im not looking for a solution - I just want to know if its possible...

Comment: Then the answer is: yes.

Comment: Thank you - glad to know its not an impossible function to create. you're help is appreciated.

Comment: Now that you have the pseudocode, you should convert that to actual JavaScript. We can help if you get stuck while implementing it.

Comment: @TomO. thank you, will keep working on it and hopefully will have some actual code down this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for this you can create the HTML element with `document.[createElement](<typeOfElement>)`, apply them attributes with `<element>.[setattribute]('<attribute>', '<valueOfTheAttribute>)` and then appending it to an existing element with `<element>.[appendChild](<child>)`.

Also you can use `<element>.innerHTML` or `<element>.outerHTML` for modifying the DOM directly without need of creating an element and appending it.